# electric planer adjustment

Tags: planer

The plates on the bottom of my electric planer are not on one level when the planer is set to zero. Is there anything I can do about this?[image]

Comment: I don’t think they’re supposed to be on the same level. The lower plate in the photo guides the plane where the wood comes in. The upper plate guides the plane where the wood goes out, after it’s been cut.

Comment: what manufacturer and model is your planer?

Comment: It's a Bauker PL823

Comment: @PeteBecker but here the lower plate is the plate where the wood goes out.

Comment: @PeteBecker, other way around Pete! :-)

Comment: @Graphus -- I could **swear** that it looked different last night. <g>

Comment: I don't think a lot of electric hand planes are designed to be 'finishing' planes, they are 'rougher'.  While that is a decent gap, I personally wouldn't want to use one to try and just take off .5mm.

Comment: @PeteBecker, ^_^ we've all done pretty much the same thing.

Comment: @bowlturner, agree in principle, although 0.5mm is quite large by planing standards! Hand planers *can* be used with finesse if they can be set up right and are adjusted correctly (and according to a manual I checked at random, apparently some can be adjusted in increments of 0.1mm, which I'm quite impressed by). But really for anything other than framing work I think they shine in the equivalent of the scrub plane or jack plane role where you want to remove a lot of material fast, and relatively effortlessly.

Comment: Have you been able to find out anything that would allow the adjustments necessary?

Comment: @Graphus apparently the day after reading your advice the plane started emitting a weird smell and a few minutes after that it broke... .

Comment: Well that's unfortunate! Sorry to hear that. Taken together with the problem that you asked about it would seem that either A) you got a bad one (made last thing on a Friday as the joke goes) or B) these just aren't good tools.